# winforms - simple form, how to iterate all the buttons in it (Visual Sudito 2010 + C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

For now I have created a `Windows Forms Project` with a single form and six `buttons` added. What I want to do right now is find out how I can iterate through all my buttons and the goal is to set the background color of every button with an even number a different color. Like - `button1 - white`, `button2-red`, `button3-white`, `button4-red` and so on. Right know I don't know either how to iterate the buttons or change the `background color` property but the questions is about iterating so I'd appreciate help about this topic if someone knows how to change the `background color` of the button it will save me time and maybe new question here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537253/922198

Comment: How are you storing the buttons? An array/list or individual variables? More context would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to .NET so I try to work step by step and I tried to make myself as clear as possible. I made my `Windows Forms` project and just added 6 buttons to it. So I can see how I can iterate them and change their properties. The next step is to change the number of the buttons dynamicly but for now `Lews Therin` answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it an array or list of buttons? Then you could do:

```
buttons.Select((btn,index)=>{
            if(index%2==0)btn.BackgroundColor=Color.Red
            else
                 btn.BackgroundColor=Color.White;
       });
```

Comment: This is what I needed. But thanks to all. And for helping me do the two jobs together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls) // this is the form object on which Controls is the ControlCollection
{
   if(c is Button)
   {
       KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
       KnownColor color= names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
       Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
       c.BackColor = color;
   }
}
```

Comment: mihirj this answer is not correct.. read the full Question from the OP

Comment: I have rightly addressed this part of the question: but the questions is about iterating so I'd appreciate help about this topic if someone knows how to change the background color of the button it will save me time.

Comment: yes that correct but he wants alternating color unless I am not reading his question properly. your looping thru the controls is totally correct.. but I was just questioning the color setting of every button the same color.. that's all

Comment: maybe this new random colors selection is what will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            Button button = control as Button;
            if (button == null) continue;
            switch (button.Name)
            {
                case "button1":
                    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    button.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "button3":
                    button.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                default:
                    button.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;

            }
        }
```